# Python Matplotlib Hist2d with 2d array

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to make a 2d histogramme by putting two 2D array as argument, Tx and alt_array, same size (56000,40)

```
def histo_2D(alt, Tx):  
u,v = 56000,40
Tx = np.zeros((u,v))
alt_array = np.zeros((u,v))
alt,tx = np.zeros((v)), np.zeros((v))
for i in range(0,v):
    alt[i] = i
    tx[i] = i
alt_array[:][:] = alt 
Tx[:][:] = tx
    alt_array[:][:] = alt 
    print np.shape(Tx), np.shape(alt_array)
    plt.hist2d(Tx , alt_array)
```

But when i try to execute my program, i get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "goccp.py", line 516, in <module>
    histo_2D(alt,Tx)
  File "goccp.py", line 376, in histo_2D
    plt.hist2d(Tx , alt_array)
  File "/Code/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2847, in hist2d
    weights=weights, cmin=cmin, cmax=cmax, **kwargs)
  File "/Code/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8628, in hist2d
    normed=normed, weights=weights)
  File "/Code/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 650, in histogram2d
    hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights)
  File "/Code/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 288, in histogramdd
    N, D = sample.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I've tried to use flattened array, but the result is not really good...

Comment: Can I have a runnable sample? And why would you avoid giving us the `print`'s output?

Comment: cause i thought it was useless, it prints (56205, 40) (56205, 40)

Comment: I've edited with a runnable version, with false value but still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `hist2d`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d) states:

> matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d(x, y, bins=10, range=None, normed=False, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, hold=None, **kwargs)
>
> *Parameters:* x, y: array_like, shape (n, ) :

Thus `x` and `y` need to be one dimensional; your values are two dimensional.

Have a look at the example as well, given at the end of the documentation.